# java String to prove equality

Tags: java, string, hashcode

```
class Foo{}
class Boo{}
class MyString
{
 public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
 {
     String s1="Hello";
     String s2="Hello";
     String s3=new String("Hello");
     System.out.println(s1.hashCode()+" "+(s1==s2));
     System.out.println(s2.hashCode());
     System.out.println(s3.hashCode()+" "+(s2==s3));
     System.out.println(new Boo().hashCode());
     System.out.println(new Foo().hashCode());
 }
}
```

Output of the above mentioned code is 

`69609650 true
69609650
69609650 false
17351095
9318325`

Because of literal pool s1 and s2 refers to the same object so `s1==s2` gives true. And s3 is a String object created by using **new** keyword.So `s2==s3` gives false.
*I tried to prove that s2 and s3 are in different location by using `hashCode()`*
Then i came to know *different objects need not to have different `hashCodes` and String content is used to produce `hashCode` value*

So my question is 
how to prove that s2 and s3 are in different memory locations? (except by using ==) *Is there any inbuilt method to check the memory location?*
If `hashCode` value is calculated for Strings by using its contents ,then how it is working for `new Foo().hashCode()`?

Comment: `Is there any inbuilt method to check the memory location` That's what `==` is for.

Comment: Look up the javadoc of `Object.hashCode()`. It explains everything you're asking.

Comment: You might want to have a look at `System#identityHashCode(Object)` as well

Answer (score 0):

> how it is working for new Foo().hashCode()

First you need to understand that `hashCode()` method is implemented by `Object` class.
And `String` class has just overridden this method to provide a mechanism to calculate hashCode of string objects differently.

So, `new Foo().hashCode()` uses the defualt hashCode() implementation provided by `Object` class. As `Foo` class has not provided its own hashCode() implementation by overriding it.

The default `hashCode()` (native method) provided by Object class simply uses the memory reference of object to calculate the hashcode value.